# Encrypt data in react-native and decrypt in .NET (C#)?

Tags: react-native, .net-core, encryption, cryptojs

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt some sensitive data in my application. So I have mobile app in react-native and api in .NET 7. But I cannot find the solution. What I want to do?

I want to encrypt my sensitive info in react-native and send the data to the api application and decrypt it in .NET api app.

The code is my encryption in react-native:

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import {iv, key} from '../../secretKey';

export function Encrypt(data) {
  const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(17);

  const encryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, key, {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    iv: iv,
  }).toString();

  const result = {
    chiperText: encryptedData.toString(),
    iv: iv,
  };

  return result;
}
```

Below code is my DecryptionHandler.cs:

```
        private static byte[] DeriveKeyFromPassword(string password)
        {
            var emptySalt = Array.Empty<byte>();
            var iterations = 1000;
            var desiredKeyLength = 16; // 16 bytes equal 128 bits.
            var hashMethod = HashAlgorithmName.SHA384;
            return Rfc2898DeriveBytes.Pbkdf2(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password),
                                             emptySalt,
                                             iterations,
                                             hashMethod,
                                             desiredKeyLength);
        }
        public static string DecryptStringAES(string cipherText)
        {

            var keybytes = DeriveKeyFromPassword(keySecret);
            var iv = DeriveKeyFromPassword(keySecret);

            var encrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            var decriptedFromJavascript = DecryptStringFromBytes(encrypted, keybytes, iv);
            return string.Format(decriptedFromJavascript);
        }

        private static string DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            }
            if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            }
            if (iv == null || iv.Length <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            }

            // Declare the string used to hold
            // the decrypted text.
            string plaintext = null;

            // Create an RijndaelManaged object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (var rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                //Settings
                rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                rijAlg.FeedbackSize = 128;

                rijAlg.Key = key;
                rijAlg.IV = iv;

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                var decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);
                try
                {
                    // Create the streams used for decryption.
                    using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                    {
                        using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {

                            using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                            {
                                // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                                // and place them in a string.
                                plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();

                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    plaintext = ex.Message;
                }
            }

            return plaintext;
        }
```

My controller api to decrypt the coming data from client side:

```
        [HttpPost("decrypt")]
        public IActionResult Decrypt([FromBody] RegisterModel model)
        {
            string decryptedData = EncryptionHandler.DecryptStringAES(model.ChiperText);
            // use decryptedData in your API logic

            return Ok(new { decryptedData });
        }
```

**Result**
I am getting *"Padding is invalid and cannot be removed."* error! I need just encrypt my data in secure way and decrypt.

I am trying to encrypt data with "Encrypt" method in react-native and decrypt in .NET with "DecryptStringAES" method. But I got **"Padding is invalid and cannot be removed."** error.

Comment: Why does your IV have 17 bytes? For AES the IV has 16 bytes (=block size of AES). Also, the encryption logic of CryptoJS depends on the data type of the key. Is this a string or WordArray? Post non-productive test data: key, IV, ciphertext.

Comment: I changed AES block size to 16 (const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);)

key: "abcdefghijklmnop"
iv: "4874815e47bcc022a55dad6a4ca3a79c"
cipherText: "U2FsdGVkX19pWDEWvO4GrSsFAoG2fs6CJ0Ln2GuNIvk=" which is equal to "1111111" value

Comment: You can only change the IV, not the AES block size. The latter is always 16 bytes for AES.

Comment: Since your key is a string, CryptoJS uses a key derivation function (`EVP_BytesToKey()`). Regarding the result format (`toString()`), see the documentation. In the C# code PBKDF2 is applied. So the key derivations are incompatible.

Comment: I changed also "var keybytes = DeriveKeyFromPassword("abcdefghijklmnop");" which latter count is 16 for AES. 
Please, could you give a code example by using my below code to correct my mistake?

Comment: I solved the issue by doing some changes in both react-native and .NET side. Thanks a lot.